# Output JS and HTML to different locations using Gulp Usemin

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-usemin

I'm using gulp-usemin to combine my JS files (with uglify)

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
Top
  |- Web
      |- Scripts
         |- App
             |- script1.js
             |- script2.js
         |- Vendor (folder)
         |- CompiledScripts
             |- useminFile1.js
      |- Areas
          |- Area1
              |- index.html
```

All the usecases for gulp-usemin designate copying everything to a `dist` folder, which I cannot do.

The goal is to rewrite the index.html file to it's current location, but to write the combined JS files to 'Top/Web/Scripts/CompiledScripts'. I've tried various combinations but I can only get JS **OR** html in the correct place, never both.

I've put the basic task below. This will output the re-written index file in the correct location, but not the compiled JS files (will be in same directory as the html file, put at the path in the html block).

```
gulp.src('./Top/Web/Areas/Area1/index.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
        path: './Top/Web/',
        assetsDir: './Top/Web/',
        js: [
            uglify()
        ]
    }))
    .pipe( gulp.dest( './Top/Web/Areas/Area1/' ) );
```

HTML Block. Needs to have absolute path to scripts

```
<!-- build:js /Scripts/CompiledModules/Libraries/test.js -->
    <script src="/Scripts/Vendor/Bower/lodash/dist/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Vendor/Bower/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Trying more combinations as we speak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have:

```
.pipe( gulp.dest( './Top/Web/Areas/Area1/' ) );
```

You need to use:

```
<!-- build:js ../../Scripts/CompiledScripts/vendor.min.js -->
```

Comment: That seemed to accomplish a little bit of my problem. Now i'll just pump the index files through to remove the relative path. Thanks

Comment: Np. Be aware that there's a couple of bugs for usemin that might confuse you when trying to set this up. (look at github repo). I ended up using useref instead, and it works great together with gulp-if.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'll be looking into that as I have multiple blocks in the same file.